# Is it possible to have a private setter in base class set from derived class without being public?

Tags: c#, getter-setter

Is it possible to give private access to a base class setter and only have it available from the inheriting classes, in the same way as the protected keyword works?

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass()
    {
        // Want to allow MyProperty to be set from this class but not
        // set publically
        public MyProperty = "abc";
    }
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with 'public string MyProperty { get; protected set; }'?:s

Comment: You're describing the "protected" modifier, then saying "in the same way the protected modifier works".

Comment: you mention the `protected` keyword... why don't you use it?

Comment: @DrewR - apologies - typo

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why don't you use `protected`?

```
public string MyProperty { get; protected set; }
```

[protected (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know you could set the protected keyword on a property!

Answer (score 3):

You only need to make the setter as [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) like:

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass()
    {
        // Want to allow MyProperty to be set from this class but not
        // set publically
        MyProperty = "abc";
    }
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; protected set; }
}
```

See also [Access Modifiers (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) instead of private.

Answer (score 0):

Protected is the right approach, but for the sake of discussion, it's possible to set a private property this way:

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass() : base(myProperty: "abc") { }
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }

    public MyBaseClass(string myProperty) { 
        this.MyProperty = myProperty;
    }
}
```